# "for" loop in shell that go over directories

Tags: shell, for-loop, subdirectory

I have a directory of 24 sub-directories, no chronological order
I need to enter a sub directory, unzip a file there and then call "tophat" command on the unzipped file, then move to the next sub-directory. the loop should go over all the sub-directories with these commands.
I don't really know how to create this loop (I need it to run on a display and not according to numeric order)

(for sure many of you who work with RNA-seq results are familiar with this issue) 
If anyone can help me with it
I'll be very thankful

Comment: does tophat can be used as `unzip -c file |tophat `

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in "/path/to/"*/
do
    cd "$d" || continue
    unzip the_file.zip
    tophat the_file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`:

```
find /path -type d -print | \
while read path ; do
    ...
done
```

Note: This loop breaks when the file names contain new line characters.

Answer (score -1):

Same using for loop

```
for directory in `find /path -type d -print`
do
    cd "$directory"
    unzip zip_filename
    sh zip_dir/script_file.sh &
done
```

Comment: Iterating over the output of `find` like this is not safe; it breaks when filenames contain the current word-splitting character.